# Gradle javadoc multi-line option not working

Tags: gradle, javadoc

Gradle javadoc with option (bottom) multi-line:

```
task myJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    ...

    options {

        bottom """
                <div>
                Foo $version <br/>
                &copy; 2016-2017 All rights reserved.
                """
    }
}
```

Error

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "1.0<br/>"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "&copy;"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "2016-2017"
```

If the option `bottom` changed to a simple text, it will work.

```
bottom "this is some text"
```

### UPDATE

The javadoc.options created under $buildDir/tmp/myJavadoc

```
-locale 'en_US'
-bottom '
                <div>
                Foo true <br/>
                &copy; 2016-2017 All rights reserved.
                '
-charset 'UTF-8'
-classpath ...
```

Is this correct?

If I run javadoc directly outside gradle using the generated option file, got the same error. So javadoc does not support multi-line as above

```
> javadoc @build\tmp\myJavadoc\javadoc.options
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you run with the right task `myJavadoc` not `javadoc`.

Your code works for me:

```
task myJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava

    options {

        bottom """
            <div>
            Foo $version <br/>
            &copy; 2016-2017 All rights reserved.
            """
    }
}
```

Here is the snapshot of the generated bottom:
[image: generated javadoc]

Comment: yes. it is not built-in javadoc. It does not work for me. It works for one line: e.g., bottom "this is some text"